# Swift: Install package so available to any Xcode Project?

Tags: swift, xcode, package, realm

Here, as an example package: Realm for Swift.

I'm trying to install Realm on macOS so that it may be available to ANY existing and future Swift project in Xcode.

However, all the installation guides, including the official https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/ talks about adding it to a specific project or target.

Using cocoapods is the same story, i must add the library to a specific "target". I probably haven't understood what a target is...? https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/using-cocoapods.html

When using Xcode's package manager (PM) to include a dependency via the github package link (for RealSwift: https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa) it seems like this process has to be repeated on a per-project basis. Neither the "next" project itself nor the PM will even take notice of a previous installation done by the PM!? On the contrary, the PM will happily go through a lengthy process of installing the package *again* for the new project. And, of course, an even lengthier compilation of the package will be repeated...

I also searched in general, for any library/package, how to make it globally available from within Xcode. Surprisingly, no luck with answers to this specific "global-versus-project"-availability issue.

Pretty confused here, please if anybody can tell this noob how to install Realm (for Swift) (or any package/library) so that it will be available to add to and use in *any* Xcode project. Also, ideally, it should be able to automatically check for updates.

Comment: You have to create a pod file first. Create a project, open the terminal and go to the folder. Then 'pod init'. It will create a `PodFile` and then in it you have to add `pod RealmSwift`, then back to terminal and `pod install`. This will install the `Realm` to your project/target. You can select the target in pod file as well. You have to install `cocoa pods` globally, run `sudo gem install cocoapods` in terminal.

Comment: @Rob thx, but this sounds like being a project-local installation / configuration of the package? when i open a new swift, project, will i have to repeat the process?

Comment: Yes. There's difference between a global package and project needed libraries. Realm is project specific and node or java or cocoa pods or home-brew are globals.

Comment: @Rob, thx. i must admit that i find it a little puzzling:-o it seems like a resonable and general use-case that you would want to install a library ABC in such a way that it may be globally available, perhaps requiring a qualified import statement like in c/c++ ```import mylibs/ABC``` instead of ```import ABC```

Comment: for Realm the correct github address is https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa and *does* load/work with Xcode PM (though, strangely, the Realm folks do not mention this possibility for installation). However, this still results in a project-dependant installation it would seem: it is not immediately available to other projects and *they* will happy reinstall Realm via the PM without detecting an existing installation that was done for a previous project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not something that Swift supports at the current time.

What you could do is clone the Git repo for a project, and then reference it as a local dependency, but I wouldn't recommend this.